# Можно ли установить пакет через conda без консольного скачивания?

Tags: python-3.x, conda

Нужно установить `m2w64-toolchain`.
Попробовал выполнить
   `conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/msys2 m2w64-toolchain`
Некоторые пакеты качает очень медленно, разрывается соединение.
Попробовал их скачать через менеджер закачек напрямую с сайта.

Как теперь установить их?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
conda install <путь к файлу-пакету>
```